# Can I set multi-on-select on grid panel cells in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, grid, panel

Can I set multi-on-select on grid panel cells?

Hey guys, I'm fairly new to ExtJS and I was wondering if there is a way to multi-on-select grid CELLS or give the illusion of multi-on-select. By "illusion" I mean to change the CSS of the individual cell dynamically on click so that it looks like it has remained toggled.

The following is code to my Grid window
Code:

```
Ext.create ('Ext.window.Window' , {    title: this.id,
    width: 500 ,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    height: 500 ,
    modal: true,
    centered: true,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        sortable: false,
        allowDeselect: true,
        columnLines: true,
        header: false,
        sortableColumns: false,
        border: false,
        columns: [{
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'ID',
            text: 'ID',
            flex: 2
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'Title',
            text: 'Title',
            flex: 3
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'Beginner',
            text: 'Beginner',
            flex: 5
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'Intermediate',
            text: 'Intermediate',
            flex: 5
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'Advanced',
            text: 'Advanced',
            flex: 5
        }],
        // One header just for show. There's no data,
        store: Ext.getStore('disciplinesStore')
    }]
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CellModel', {
            allowDeselect: true,
            listeners: {
            select: {
                  fn: me.onCellModelSelect,
                  scope: me
                    }
              }
        })
}).show ();
```

And then

```
onCellModelSelect: function(cellmodel, record, row, column, eOpts) {

        if(column === 2){
            stuff = 'Beginner';
        }else if(column === 3){
            stuff= 'Intermediate';
        }else if(column === 4){
            stuff = 'Advanced';
        }
        Ext.Msg.alert('asd',record.get(stuff));
    }
```

Comment: What do you call by "multi-on-select"?

Comment: What if you add `mode: 'MULTI'` to your selModel properties?? [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-selModel) might help too.

Comment: So, you want select multiple cells instead of multiple records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized an alternate way of solving this;

Instead of applying a cell selector which doesnt allow `mode: 'MULTI'`, divide each of the columns into individual tables and apply a row selector or check box selector to them and set that to MULTI. Works like a charm.

As a reference for others with the same problem, it now successfully looks like this

[image]

The code of the Beginner, Intermediate and Advanced columns was replace by individual tables with a row selector function as follows

```
{
 xtype: 'gridpanel',
 flex: 2.5,
 autoRender: false,
 id: 'thegrid',
 style: 'white-space:normal',
 width: 723,
 header: false,
 title: 'My Grid Panel',
 allowDeselect: true,
 columnLines: true,
 sortableColumns: false,
 store: 'disciplinesStore',
 columns: [
     {
          xtype: 'gridcolumn',
          dataIndex: 'Beginner',
          text: 'Beginner',
          flex: 5
      }
           ],
           selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.RowModel', {
           allowDeselect: true,
           mode: 'SIMPLE',
           listeners: {
               deselect: {
                     fn: me.onRowModelDeselect,
                     scope: me
                     },
           selectionchange: {
                     fn: me.onRowModelSelectionChange,
                     scope: me
                     }
               }
         })
   }
```